# Need help in printing item in dictionary in 2 decimal places as well as spacing issue. [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

Am currently working on a program to take in TV subscriptions. I seem to have an issue during the output as sub_price["Sports Group Pack" seems to output in 1 decimal place as 21.4 instead of 21.40 which I desire. There also seem to have an output issue as I am getting spaces as such: ($ 21.4 )

The output i am aiming for is something more like ($21.40)
I also am unable to make the dollar sign stick to the last 2 numbers printing out the subscription selection. What I am getting is $ 8.56, is it possible to get it to $8.56?
Any help would be appreciated.

[Code]

```
def get_subscription():
  sub_price = {
   "Sports Group Pack":21.40,
   "Documentaries Pack":15.32,
   "FOX Movies Pack":17.12,
   "HBO Pack":13.98,
   "Cinema World":9.56,
   "Celestial Movies":8.56}
   
  print("Channels available for subscription (price/mth)")
  for key, value in sub_price.items():
    print("{0:<40}{1:>2}{2:>5.2f}".format(key,"$",value))

  sub01 = input("Subscribe to Sports Group Pack? (Y/N):").upper()
  sub02 = input("Subscribe to Documentaries Pack? (Y/N):").upper()
  sub03 = input("Subscribe to FOX Movies Pack? (Y/N):").upper()
  sub04 = input("Subscribe to HBO Pack? (Y/N):").upper()
  sub05 = input("Subscribe to Cinema World? (Y/N):").upper()
  sub06 = input("Subscribe to Celestial Movies? (Y/N):").upper()


  
  if sub01 =="N" and sub02 == "N" and sub03 == "N" and sub04 == "N" and sub05 == "N" and sub06 == "N":
    print()
    print("Your selection:")
    print(" - None")
    print()
    print("Total cost $0.00")

  sum=0
  if sub01 =="Y" or sub02 == "Y" or sub03 == "Y" or sub04 == "Y" or sub05 == "Y" or sub06 == "Y":
    print("Your selection:")

  if sub01 == "Y":
    print(" - Sports Group Pack", "($", sub_price["Sports Group Pack"],")")
    sum = sum + sub_price["Sports Group Pack"]

  if sub02 == "Y":
    print(" - Documentaries Pack", "($", sub_price["Documentaries Pack"],")")
    sum = sum + sub_price["Documentaries Pack"]

  if sub03 == "Y":
    print(" - FOX Movies Pack", "($", sub_price["FOX Movies Pack"],")")
    sum = sum + sub_price["FOX Movies Pack"]

  if sub04 == "Y":
    print(" - HBO Pack", "($", sub_price["HBO Pack"],")")
    sum = sum + sub_price["HBO Pack"]
  
  if sub05 == "Y":
    print(" - Cinema World", "($", sub_price["Cinema World"],")")
    sum = sum + sub_price["Cinema World"]

  if sub06 == "Y":
    print(" - Celestial Movies", "($", sub_price["Celestial Movies"],")")
    sum = sum + sub_price["Celestial Movies"]

  if sub01 =="Y" or sub02 == "Y" or sub03 == "Y" or sub04 == "Y" or sub05 == "Y" or sub06 == "Y":
    print()
    print("Total cost $%.2f"%sum)

get_subscription()
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK python will automatically strip the 0s from the integer, but there is a way to workaround it. You can define values in dictionary is a string:

```
 sub_price = {
   "Sports Group Pack":'21.40',
   "Documentaries Pack":'15.32',
   "FOX Movies Pack":'17.12',
   "HBO Pack":'13.98',
   "Cinema World":'9.56',
   "Celestial Movies":'8.56'}
```

And while doing calculations with them, cast to integer On-the-fly with:

```
int(sub_price['KEY_NAME'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your print statements from this

```
        print(" - Sports Group Pack", "($", sub_price["Sports Group Pack"], ")")
```

To:

```
        print(" - Sports Group Pack", "(${0:.2f})".format(sub_price["Sports Group Pack"]))
```

Which should print:

```
- Sports Group Pack ($21.40)
```

This is similar to the formatting you're already doing in the for loop at the beginning.

See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for more details